# How can I set charset for italian locale?

Tags: html, character-encoding, special-characters, locale

I am using html/javascript in smalltalk server.I have set utf-8 charset in meta tag.But italian special characters are shown not properly.For example , á is shown as Ã¡.
I have given the header values below 
Response Header :

```
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  269
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie VW-WTK-sessionkey=863807508382_ga=GA1.2.1395970228.1381994276
Host    www.example.it
Referer http://www.exapmle.it/hello.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Request Header :

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  85
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host    www.example.it
Referer http://www.example.it/index.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

And the post is

```
Parameters application/x-www-form-urlencoded

city    Ã¡ Ã  Ã¨ Ã© Ã¬ Ã­ Ã² Ã³ Ã¹ Ãº
name    Ã¡ Ã  Ã¨ Ã© Ã¬ Ã­ Ã² Ã³ Ã¹ Ãº
```

Answer (score 0):

When “á” is shown as “Ã¡”, then you have a UTF-8 encoded “á” (U+00E1), i.e. bytes 0xC3 0xA1, which is being misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252 encoded, as U+00C3 U+00A1.

The question does not specify *where* (in which program) “á” is shown as “Ã¡”, but there is at least something wrong with the request headers. The content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` has no parameters; the `charset` parameter there is ignored. When using that type, the data must be [URL-encoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data) according to the rules of the type.

Alternatively, consider using the `multipart/form-data` content type.

Comment: Thank You for answering.It happened because the file's encoding was in iso-8859-1 & utf-8, while it was called mentioning utf-8.So,browser decoded in windows 1259.